# auto increment in every 500 miliseconds flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to increment `_counter` state in every 500 milliseconds for 100 times.

So I tried this:

```
int _counter = 0;

  _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { //Loop 100 times
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () { // Delay 500 miliseconds
          _counter++; //Increment Counter
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

But its increment 0 to 100 in 1 click.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the setState() inside your Future.delayed() method. It will look like this:

```
    int _counter = 0;

    _incrementCounter() async {
      
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { //Loop 100 times
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () { // Delay 500 milliseconds
           setState(() {
            _counter++; //Increment Counter
             }
          });
        
      });
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but still its not working as i expected. its still hit to 100 direct

Comment: Await the Future.

Comment: @RobertSandberg `The await expression can only be used in an async function.` i am getting this error

Comment: Of course, we need to add the async keyword here:
 _incrementCounter() async {

Answer (score 2):

Using just the future

```
int _counter = 0;
await Future.doWhile(() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  _counter++;
  return _counter!=100;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be using [periodic Timer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html).

```dart
int counter = 0;
Timer? timer;

timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 500), ()  {
  counter ++;

  if (counter == 100) {
    timer!.cancel();
  }
});
```

Comment: it gave an "The non-nullable local variable 'timer' must be assigned before it can be used.
Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution path." error

Comment: @vontdeux, I've just updated the code. It should work now.